# Intution behind Chebyshev polynomials?

Tags: special-functions, intuition

In lecture notes on Fourier Analysis, Chebyshev Polynomials denoted by $T_{n}$ was restated as follows:

$$T_{n}(x) = \cos(n\cos^{-1}(x)) = \sum_{0 \leq j \leq\ n/2}(-1)^{j}{n \choose 2j} x^{n-2j}(1-x^{2})^{j}$$

What's the intuition behind Chebyshev Polynomials what makes them significant, what's the initial motivation ?

Comment: Please edit you question $T_n(x) = \cos(n \color{red}{\cos^{-1}}(x)) $ ?  ... &  you might want to look at https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chebyshev_polynomials AND/OR http://mathworld.wolfram.com/ChebyshevPolynomialoftheFirstKind.html

Comment: Weird did the latex not render, for you because it renders on my browser.

Answer (score 2):

They are extremely important in polynomial approximation, because they are sort of a model case: in their beloved region $[-1,1],$ they are $\le1,$ and they attain those values $\pm1$ as often as possible for a polynomial of that degree. That's important, because there's a theorem that the error of the optimal approximation of a continuous function by a polynomial will do exactly that. And that's helpful to construct optimal or at least reasonable approximations by polynomials quite often.

Comment: The question was about intuition.

Comment: And this answer provides exactly that!

Comment: @uniquesolution Then, we might propose to ask that question at Stack Exchange Intuition, right?